# como hago un insert tipo DATE en mongo compass

Tags: mongodb

En el vsCode uso:

```
db.productos.insertOne({
    "fecha_insercion": new Date(), 
})
```

Pero en el `compass` no me deja tampoco así:

```
"fecha_insercion": { ISODate("2023-09-14T21:13:32.145Z")}
"fecha_insercion": { "$date": "2023-09-14T21:13:32.145Z" }
"fecha_insercion": "2023-09-14T21:13:32.145Z"
```

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que esto lo puedes hacer manualmente, abriendo el editor de documentos, primero selecciona la base de datos y la colección que deseas modificar. Haz clic en el botón "INSERT DOCUMENT" y después el botón Insertar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Haz clic en "INSERT" para agregar un documento a tu colección, recuerda, si vas a insertar un valor tipo Date, es muy importante  asegurarte de usar el formato ISODate